# How to host widgets and how to update them always reliably?

Tags: java, android, widget

I'm hosting widgets in my app. They can be picked from a list of all installed widgets and are added to a view. I save their IDs to database and restore them from these saved IDs again after restart of the app.

This works most of the times, but not always. Widgets are not always updated properly. One scenario where that happens for sure is:

"rebooting phone and starting app before boot-process of device has finished."
(if i wait until booting is completed, it works!!!)

There must be another scenario, but i couldnt reproduce that. I restart my app and they are not updated. So i wonder if i am missing something important.

I have basically used this tutorial:

http://leonardofischer.com/hosting-android-widgets-my-appwidgethost-tutorial/#comment-14678

**My Code:**

***onCreate:***

```
mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this); 
mAWH_AppWidgetHost = new MyAppWidgetHost(MyApp.getContext(), R.string.APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);
```

***onStart:***

```
mAWH_AppWidgetHost.startListening();
```

***onStop:***

```
mAWH_AppWidgetHost.stopListening();
```

***restore from id (saved in database):***

```
AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);

MyAppWidgetHostView hostView = (MyAppWidgetHostView) mAWH_AppWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);

mLL_innerLayout.addView((MyAppWidgetHostView) hostView);
```

I cannot find any sites in the web that make this clear. Neither does looking at source code of different launcher apps make it more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but then I moved

```
mAWH_AppWidgetHost.startListening();
```

in onCreate method and

```
mAWH_AppWidgetHost.stopListening();
```

in onDestroy method. This is suggested [here](http://selvaline.blogspot.it/2015/10/hosting-widgets-and-regurally-update.html)

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i did too in the end. See my update here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642690/why-does-calling-appwidgethost-startlistening-in-onstart-not-update-hosted-wid). I dont really like this solutions since it is against the docs and has probably a lot of battery consumption, but it seems to be the only solution.